# How could I access values in a HashMap in a BIRT report

Tags: java, birt

I have a number of BIRT reports which use information in a POJO to display different sets of information.

The standard report contains a header and a list of test results. This is fine for A4 reports but I now want to be able to print labels which contain 1 or 2 items from the header (e.g. Customer) and 1 or 2 results from specific tests.

My idea is to add a HashMap to the header and add an option to tests to be able to store their result into a named location in the HashMap.

My question is: how can I access a value in the HashMap from a report which uses scripted DataSets?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was not as difficult as I had thought.

I added this to my POJO:

```
private Map<String, Object> valueMap;
public Map<String, Object> getValueMap(){ return valueMap; }
```

and added this to the main DataSet#fetch method:

```
row["ValueMap"] = p.getValueMap();
```

where the column ValueMap is defined as a Java object.

In the report I can add a DynamicText containing

```
row["ValueMap"].get('CalibrationFactor')
```

So now I can get a test to store its result value in 'CalibrationFactor', for example, and it will be displayed in the report.